# Can I reduce the clutter stickies app leaves in macOS 11.4 Apple menu > Recent Items?

Tags: macos, command-line, stickies

So, I am ancient, and I still use Stickies Running macOS Big Sur 11.4.

I use the app  a lot.

It's pretty clutch for me for a large number of reasons. One annoyance that has shown up recently:

Every time I launch Stickies, it clutters my Apple Menu's Recent Documents list with a `.rtfd` file for each individual sticky note.  Ack!!!  I have a lot of sticky notes, so this has effectively rendered my **** > **Recent Documents** list completely useless.  (I *can* set it to show a lot of documents and then scroll down past all the `.rtfd` files, but this is super inefficient on my laptop.)

I've tried looking into using a script to muck around with the contents of `~/Library/appsupport/com.apple.sharedfilelist/*.sfl2`, but unfortunately it's become readily apparent that these files are not easily modifiable using text-editing or anything like that.  `/usr/bin/sfltool` looked promising, but apparently, Apple took out a lot of the [functionality that was present in prior macOS versions](https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4985135170584576)

I am open to any suggestions on continuing to use Stickies.app but preventing it from populating/cluttering my **** > **Recent Documents** menu. I want that for other recent documents exclusively.

Can I deny Stickies.app permission to populate the recent documents list somehow, without affecting other app document’s arrival to the  menu?

Comment: Bounty for hopefully a native or script based solution. Software recommendations also are welcome but I’d hope to let the OP continue to use all the features of stickies notes by Apple.

Answer (score 1):

You could check out SideNotes. It doesn’t add anything to the recents menu so in that respect it should be much more convenient.

- https://apps.apple.com/us/app/sidenotes-thoughts-tasks/id1441958036?mt=12

It’s available on the App Store and priced at $20 for US purchase as of fall 2023.